# ошибка в коде почему-то только у меня . . . метод String не содержит определения "Dump"

Tags: c#

ОШИБКА: метод String() не содержит определения "Dump"

```
 public void Print()
        {
          "Hello World".Dump();
        }
```

Comment: У String действительно нет такого метода: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-7.0 Но можно расширить классы, добавив методы: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: спасибо вам  большое

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Оформите, пожалуйста, самостоятельно ответ на ваш вопрос, добавив пример кода :)

Comment: `Dump()` - это обычно метод сторонних решений и сервисов. Например, `LINQPad`, он позволяет таким методом выводить на экран информацию об объекте. Это не фишка языка, и в обычном коде подобный метод не нужен. Так что, не копируйте бездумно код, проанализируйте его, поймите что там нужно, а что нет.

Comment: спасибо вам большое

Answer (score 1):

получилось вот так:

```
 public class Program
  {
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      string service = "Bob";
      string str = service.Dump();
      Console.WriteLine(str);

      Console.Read();
    }
  }
  public static class ProfileService
  {
    public static string Dump(this string service)
    {
      return service;
    }
  }
```

а нужно чтобы таким был вызов:

```
string str = service.ProfileService().Dump();
```